# DirectShow Source filter using Dekstop window as source

Tags: directshow

I am looking for examples of a DirectShow Source filter that would display a Desktop Window. I am sure there should be examples, but I haven't yet found them. Perhaps I am using the wrong terminology.

This is for grabbing live output of a Window, and processing that has video.

Lee

Comment: Hi Lee were you able to get this done? I was looking for a simple example I can look at and learn from / port. So much stuff out there is so complicated for COM beginner like me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In DirectShow SDK there is a sample filter called PushSource and inside there is PushSourceDesktop. Compile it, register ("regsvr32 PushSource.ax") and insert into your graph as a source filter.

Comment: I tried the same, but my recorder program (FFmpeg, or a source from DSpack) cant see it as source. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Its mentioned at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/push-source-filters-sample

Source code for sample push source filter is at
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/filters/pushsource