# Writing a virtual webcam?

Tags: c++, python, webcam, wia

I need to create a virtual webcam that poses as a webcam, but takes as input a set of images that it plays. I have seen solutions like ManyCam, and Fake Webcam, but they all seem to one limitation or the other (resolution, max file size, fps etc.) I am working on Windows XP SP3.

I understand that I have to write a WIA interface for this task, but being a Python programmer, I have never written drivers or interfaces to devices. What are the main tasks in writing this interface ? What would the flow look like ?

Comment: unrelated advice: "don't say that you _are_ a Python programmer", you're a programmer that prefers (or only knows) Python... yet.

Comment: May be s/he's a core developer of cpython... :-)

Comment: @Javier great advice ! though it may be more of a cultural thing. 
@6502 just thinking about that made me go crazy. if I were a developer of cpython, wouldn't I be a C programmer? or I could be a python programmer because I program python

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214786/directshow-source-filter-using-dekstop-window-as-source

Answer (score 27):

You need to write DirectShow filter which is a COM server that implements an [`IPin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`IAMStreamConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`IKsPropertySet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces. For the `IPin` part you'd better to start by inheriting the [`CSourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, for that you need to get the Windows SDK, having the SDK installed there would be a DirectShow Base Classes sources in `samples\multimedia\directshow` folder, there you'll find the `CSourceStream` (among many others). `DllRegisterServer` function of the COM server should register your filter within `CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory` category using filter mapper.

After building the COM-server, you register it with `regsvr32` tool, and your virtual webcam should appear in the web cam lists.

Also check the `samples\multimedia\directshow\filters\ball` sample that can be improved and used as a starting point for your task.

Comment: Thanks you very much for detailing the flow. I will look at the samples and learn. Thanks again :)

Comment: @n0rd please help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839449/directshow-based-virtual-camera-is-not-showing-any-frame-in-zoom

Comment: Thanks @n0rd. I know this question/answer is old, but would you have a minimal example of such code? Ideally it would be a single .c or .cpp file :) PS: does the solution you describe create a virtual webcam, that can be used as a [webcam in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911688/how-to-make-my-c-code-recognized-as-a-video-source-webcam-by-chrome-browser)?

Answer (score 1):

Read this first
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/writing-source-filters

Then you can adopt
https://github.com/roman380/tmhare.mvps.org-vcam

You can work on top of this sample virtual camera.

This implements [`IAMStreamConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-iamstreamconfig) and [`IKsPropertySet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/ikspropertyset) interfaces
This is built using [`CSourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/csourcestream) and [`CSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/csource) class which implements [`IPin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-ipin) and [`IBaseFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-ibasefilter)