# How to make virtual video port, direct it to avd emulator and play video file on it?

Tags: java, video-streaming, driver, hardware, virtualization

On Test Automation framework I need to play my custom video file on virtual video port directed to AVD emulator and control this process from code.
**How can I do this using java?**
Video file for streaming generated at runtime.
Currently we use simple [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org) scenario for putting video file to [ManyCam](https://download.manycam.com) virtual camera. *(actually, my question is aimed at getting rid of this)*
TA framework: TestNG, AndroidDriver, Appium, Maven, AVD, Allure...
**There is any chance to make DirectShow COM-server using Java?** 
instruction for WIN SDK there :

- [Writing a virtual webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243891/writing-a-virtual-webcam)
- [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream)

I can't get how to start to do something like that using java

**UPDATE:**
Our temporary  solution is to use ManyCam paid version (Standard - **20$** per year)
This version makes possible to redirect custom video stream from server to virtual Camera
To implement video-stream-server we used standard java classes **HttpServer**, **BufferedImage** and **javax.imageio** package