# Using Python to access DirectShow to create and use Virtual Camera(Software Only Camera)

Tags: python, windows, directshow, pywin32, win32com

Generally to create a Virtual Camera we need to create a C++ application and include DirectShow API to achieve this. But with the modules such as
win32 modules and other modules we can use win32 api which lets us use these apis in python.

Can anyone Help sharing a good documentation or some Sample codes for doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a virtual webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243891/writing-a-virtual-webcam)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to emulate a webcam on Windows otherwise than supplying a driver. Many applications take simpler path with DirectShow, and emulate a webcam for a subset of DirectShow based applications (in particular, modern apps will be excluded since they don't use DirectShow), but even in this case you have to develop C++ camera enumation code and connect your python code with it.