# Set byte stream as live source in Expression Encoder 4

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, expression-encoder

I have Expression Encoder 4 which supports two sort of source types:

1. Live Source and
2. File Source

Now, I want to achieve my byte stream to  be set as live source in Expression Encoder for live broadcasting. I have read about directshow filters but I do not know how to use it. Please let me know if you get something on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical solution is to implement a virtual camera and stream data off it. Encoder will see it as a video capture device and you will be able to select it as a video source.

See also:

- [DirectShow Capture Devices in Expression Encoder 4](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/42f7f629-9613-41ef-9a0f-d2c9ca57cd4f)
- ["Fake" DirectShow video capture device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376734/fake-directshow-video-capture-device)
- [Writing a Direct Show Source Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413769/writing-a-direct-show-source-filter)

Briefly:

1. The closest SDK sample to a virtual video source is [Push Source Filters Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. A well known non-SDK sample for virtual camera is [VCam](http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm) project
3. To quick check if the whole thing is going to work out with EE4, you can install a [virtual video device wrapper over JPEG/M-JPEG IP cameras](http://alax.info/blog/1223), set it up to take picture from some internet live demo and check it against Encoder 4 for compatibility and integration details

Comment: Can you give me example of writting DirectShow Filter or setting existing filter as live source in Expression Encoder?

Comment: I would check your points written and test them on my machine and see how it goes and let you know in case of any issues.please stay with me.

Comment: I have tried your given options but I dont know how to use it I mean I need to have my byte stream which is raw video, I need to pass that as live source to Expression Encoder and for that I need to have virtual camera or virtual Video capture device which takes my passed video streams. This thing I can not implement.
Please Help me out

Comment: `PushSource` and `VCam` above do generate data, and it could be from a memory byte stream - as an option.

Comment: If you have anything as an example please show me coz I dont know how to use it. I have tried myself but could not make it. Help me in this

Comment: this link seems to be useful but I dont know in what editor to use and to write program and how to? Please let me know on the above if you know anything..

Comment: I am confused, you are not sure that `Visual Studio` is the development environment to use and `MSDN` is source of technical information?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Expression Encoder which is the same as Flash Media Encoder for flash. However, I am using silverlight. Basically, in Expression Encoder, there are two source types. Live and File Source as I stated first, in Live we can set the Web Cam video capture to broadcast it live. Now I want to set Other client's Web cam as the live source of my host's Expression Encoder. And I am already getting the streams on the server using web service.Which I want to set as the live source of Expression Encoder.

Comment: And I read somewhere it can be accomplished using making DirectShow Filter so I am trying but could not so far. Please help me out in this