# How can I send video frame to virtual camera

Tags: c, video, ms-media-foundation

I've done a project about image process using 'OpenCV', and I want to send my result image to virtual camera to show on skype.

I google many information like "DirectShow", "media foundation", "[v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)"...

Finally, I've trying to use "media foundation" to do, and I studied [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms697062(v=vs.85).aspx) to learn how to do.

Now I can use media foundation to get "Real" camera device, but no virtual camera(I've already register a VCam) in enumeration.

Could any one give some hint or another way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: what is a 'virtual camera' ? are you asking, how to send a stream over the network ?

Comment: Virtual camera is not real hardware device.
It's use software to register in system.(Perhaps)
And I want to send stream to my virtual camera(Local side)
It's not over network!

Comment: The question wording makes an assumption that some virtual camera might exist or can be created, then you just communicate with with supplying your content. No, it does not work this way. You have to implement it in full and register with the API or even hook the API, so that your fake device is taken as real, and then you communicate with it. There are no good samples available that I am aware of, for Media Foundation.

Comment: Then another note is that desktop version of Skype does not use Media Foundation for media capture, it uses DirectShow. Windows Store version, however, is likely to use Media Foundation.

Comment: let me remove the opencv tag, it's neither related, nor helpful. (since opencv can't help you here at all, being a computer-vision library with some video-input buckled upon)

Comment: Thank you "Roman R" and "berak". Understand my bad English...
@Roman R : It means I must write a API use directShow and include every process I want to do? Could you give some more hints about this. Thank you !

Comment: You will find some leads here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314513/how-to-create-directshow-filter/17314710#17314710

Comment: Thank you very much Roman R., it's very helpful for me.